# How does Android handle unknown XML tags?

Tags: android, xml, android-version

According to Android Lint, some XML attributes cause crashes on older devices.  For example, `Attribute 'paddingStart' referenced here can result in a crash on some specific devices older than API 17`

Does this mean I need separate XML files to support unknown tags (e.g. the same layout with the `paddingStart` attribute added in a `layout-v17` resource directory)?

I don't like the idea of having an extra, nearly identical file, as this is prone to errors when I update my code.  Will some devices actually crash? I would've thought unknown tags would just be ignored.

Comment: You can use old tags such as marginLeft instead.

Comment: Usually it's easier to use the older backward-compatible tags/attributes, if you are supporting older devices, since the backward compatibility should not break functionality on newer devices. If the backward compatibility is not satisfactory and you still need to support older devices, then you need to have separate files or logic to account for those api differences.

Comment: Either you limit your application to higher apis from the manifest or you refrain from using such attributes, that's my advice.

Answer (score -2):

To my knowledge, you should be able to use both the `paddingLeft` and 'paddingStart' without resulting in any errors. Attributes like `paddingStart` are used for setting up a left-to-right layout or in some countries a right-to-left layout, were in that case the 'start' would be on the right hand side of the screen.

So, to summarise, use `paddingLeft`, `paddingRight`, `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom`.